# Trying load test an application on my phone error keeps saying "Unable to delete directory:

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Trying load the application(test on my phone) but this error keeps coming up

```
Unable to delete directory 'C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\191c94df5fd2d7bdfb73b3f75afa22c0'
  Failed to delete some children. This might happen because a process has files open or has its working directory set in the target directory.
  - C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\191c94df5fd2d7bdfb73b3f75afa22c0\aapt2-4.0.1-6197926-windows
```

I have tried cleaning the project then testing it again but it still same error

I have also tried Rebuilding the project but it is still the same error

I tried invalidate and restart, after invalidate and restart I tried testing the app but it is still the same.

what is wrong and how can I solve this?

Comment: delete the file mentioned there manually

Comment: after shutting down android studio